# Issue silent notifications in android

Tags: java, android

I've read about the notification documentation and audiomanager. I've come across `adjustStreamVolume` method and `STREAM_NOTIFICATION` flag. What I'm not understanding at all is how exactly should I apply both this methods if I want to notify the user in silence? Supposing I have the following notification:

```
notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext())
         .setContentTitle(notification_title)
         .setContentText(notification_text)
         .setTicker("Notification!")
         .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
         .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND).setAutoCancel(true)
         .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_stat_name).build();

//and show with notification manager
```

where exactly does adjustStreamVolume and STREAM_NOTIFICATION fit in all of these?

Comment: Don't specify that you want the  `DEFAULT_SOUND` when you want silence. AudioManager volume settings are only useful if you want to change them globally.

Comment: @zapl And I could, indeed... I want all my notifications to be silent...

Comment: global as in not your for your app, for every app. That's the volume slider you find in a device's system settings somewhere.